# Keep before and after date of an external list

Tags: r

Having this dataframe:

```
dframe1 <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), name = c("Google", 
"Yahoo", "Amazon", "Amazon", "Google"), date = c("2008-11-01", 
"2008-11-01", "2008-11-04", "2008-11-01", "2008-11-02")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

And this second one:

```
    dframe2 <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), date = c("2008-11-01", "2008-11-01", 
"2008-11-04", "2008-10-31", "2008-10-31", "2008-11-02", "2008-11-02", 
"2008-11-02", "2008-11-05", "2008-11-02", "2008-11-03", "2008-10-31", 
"2008-11-01", "2008-11-01", "2008-11-02", "2008-11-02", "2008-11-03"
), name = c("Google", "Yahoo", "Amazon", "Google", "Yahoo", "Amazon", 
"Google", "Yahoo", "Amazon", "Google", "Yahoo", "Amazon", "Google", 
"Amazon", "Google", "Amazon", "Google"), text_sth = c("test", 
"text_sth", "text here", "another text", "other", "another one", 
"test", "text_sth", "text here", "another text", "other", "etc", 
"test", "text_sth", "text here", "another text", "text here")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-17L))
```

Using the results of dframe1 how is it possible to keep from dataframe2 the rows which have the same name for every id as dframe1 but one date before and after the record date of dframe1?

Here what I tried

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)

dframe1 = data.table(dframe1)
dframe1[, date := as.Date(date)]

dframe1_first = dframe1[, .(date = min(date)), .(id, name)] %>% 
    mutate(date_pre = date - 1,
           date_after = date + 1)

req_rows = dframe2 %>%
    merge(dframe1_first %>%
              rename(id = id),
          by = "id") %>%
    filter(date >= date_pre,
           date <= date_after,
           date != date) %>%
    mutate(period = ifelse(date<date, '1-day-pre', '1-day-after'))
```

Expected output:

> ```
>  id       date   name     text_sth
> 1 2008-10-31 Google another text
> 1 2008-10-31  Yahoo        other
> 1 2008-11-02 Google         test
> 1 2008-11-02  Yahoo     text_sth
> 1 2008-11-05 Amazon    text here
> 1 2008-11-02 Google another text
> 2 2008-10-31 Amazon          etc
> 2 2008-11-01 Google         test
> 2 2008-11-02 Amazon another text
> 2 2008-11-03 Google    text here
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be to expand `dframe1` dataset and include rows with has +1 and -1 `date` for each `id` and `name`. We remove the original rows of `dframe1` and do an `inner_join` with `dframe2`.

```
library(dplyr)

dframe1 %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date), date1 = date) %>%
  group_by(id, name) %>%
  tidyr::complete(date1 = seq(date1 - 1, date1 + 1, by = "1 day")) %>%
  filter(date1 != date | is.na(date)) %>%
  select(-date) %>%
  rename(date = 3) %>%
  inner_join(dframe2 %>% mutate(date = as.Date(date)))

#Joining, by = c("id", "name", "date")
# A tibble: 10 x 4
# Groups:   id, name [5]
#      id name   date       text_sth    
#   <int> <chr>  <date>     <chr>       
# 1     1 Amazon 2008-11-05 text here   
# 2     1 Google 2008-10-31 another text
# 3     1 Google 2008-11-02 test        
# 4     1 Google 2008-11-02 another text
# 5     1 Yahoo  2008-10-31 other       
# 6     1 Yahoo  2008-11-02 text_sth    
# 7     2 Amazon 2008-10-31 etc         
# 8     2 Amazon 2008-11-02 another text
# 9     2 Google 2008-11-01 test        
#10     2 Google 2008-11-03 text here
```

To add a new columns we can add another `mutate` statement.

```
dframe1 %>%
   mutate(date = as.Date(date), date1 = date) %>%
   group_by(id, name) %>%
   tidyr::complete(date1 = seq(date1 - 1, date1 + 1, by = "1 day")) %>%
   filter(date1 != date | is.na(date)) %>%
   select(-date) %>%
   mutate(col = c("before", "after")) %>%
   rename(date = 3) %>%
   inner_join(dframe2 %>% mutate(date = as.Date(date)))
```

Comment: Is there any possibility to add a column which will show if it is previous or after date?

Comment: @Nathalie Updated the answer. I have added `c("before", "after")` but you can choose anything which you want.

Comment: Thank you. One more question. If the dframe2 didn't have the name column how can I make this process https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58643662/keep-records-before-and-after-a-specific-timestamp?noredirect=1#comment103594087_58643662

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to find matching entries on `id`, `name` and the day before or the day after. Therefore, a *non-equi join* will not help as it will include matches on the day itself.

I suggest to perform two inner joins, one for the day before and a second for the day after using `lapply()`. Subsequently, the results are combined with `rbindlist()` which also adds a new column `matching_day` [as requested by the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58141008/keep-before-and-after-date-of-an-external-list#comment102674124_58143687):

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
setDT(dframe1)[, date := as.Date(date)]
setDT(dframe2)[, date := as.Date(date)]

lapply(
  c(-1, +1), 
  function(x) dframe2[dframe1[, .(id, name, date = date + x)], on = .(id, name, date), nomatch = 0L]
) %>%
  set_names(c("before", "after")) %>% 
  rbindlist(idcol = "matching_day") %>% 
  .[order(id)]
```

> ```
>     matching_day id       date   name     text_sth
>  1:       before  1 2008-10-31 Google another text
>  2:       before  1 2008-10-31  Yahoo        other
>  3:        after  1 2008-11-02 Google         test
>  4:        after  1 2008-11-02 Google another text
>  5:        after  1 2008-11-02  Yahoo     text_sth
>  6:        after  1 2008-11-05 Amazon    text here
>  7:       before  2 2008-10-31 Amazon          etc
>  8:       before  2 2008-11-01 Google         test
>  9:        after  2 2008-11-02 Amazon another text
> 10:        after  2 2008-11-03 Google    text here
> ```

Answer (score 0):

A base R way could be to transform `dframe1` into a data frame `dframe1a` that already consists of the desired dates and `merge()` with `dframe2`.

```
dframe1a <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1:nrow(dframe1), function(m) 
  cbind(dframe1[m, -3], date=as.matrix(dframe1[m, "date"] + c(-1, 1)), row.names=NULL)))
dframe1a$date <- as.Date(as.numeric(as.character(dframe1a$date)), origin="1970-01-01")
merge(dframe2, dframe1a)
#    id       date   name     text_sth
# 1   1 2008-10-31 Google another text
# 2   1 2008-10-31  Yahoo        other
# 3   1 2008-11-02 Google another text
# 4   1 2008-11-02 Google         test
# 5   1 2008-11-02  Yahoo     text_sth
# 6   1 2008-11-05 Amazon    text here
# 7   2 2008-10-31 Amazon          etc
# 8   2 2008-11-01 Google         test
# 9   2 2008-11-02 Amazon another text
# 10  2 2008-11-03 Google    text here
```

*Note:* Of course your origin dates need to be formatted as such, e.g. `dframe1$date <- as.Date(dframe1$date)`.