# Create a specific output using id and timestamp from anothe dataframe

Tags: r

Having a dataframe like this:

```
dfirst <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), date = c("2008-11-01", "2008-11-01", "2008-11-04", "2008-10-31", 
"2008-10-31", "2008-11-02", "2008-11-02", "2008-11-02", "2008-11-05", 
"2008-11-02", "2008-11-03"), text_sth = c("test", "text_sth", 
"text here", "another text", "other", "another one", "test", 
"text_sth", "text here", "another text", "other")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

And a second dataframe like this:

```
dsecond <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L), name = c("Google", "Yahoo", 
"Amazon"), date = c("2008-11-01", "2008-11-01", "2008-11-04")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

How is it possible to create an output which will contain the previous and after date as recorded in second data filter in data frame 1 data

> ```
> id       date     text_sth   name label
> 1 2008-10-31 another text Google   pre
> 1 2008-10-31        other Google   pre
> 1 2008-11-02  another one Google after
> 1 2008-11-02         test Google after
> 1 2008-11-02     text_sth Google after
> 1 2008-11-02 another text Google after
> 1 2008-10-31 another text  Yahoo   pre
> 1 2008-10-31        other  Yahoo   pre
> 1 2008-11-02  another one  Yahoo after
> 1 2008-11-02         test  Yahoo after
> 1 2008-11-02     text_sth  Yahoo after
> 1 2008-11-02 another text  Yahoo after
> 1 2008-11-03        other Amazon   pre
> 1 2008-11-05    text here Amazon after
> ```

Comment: @d.b from dfirst I try sth like this `dfirst %>%
    merge(dsecond ,
          by = c("date", "id") %>%
              filter(date >= date_pre,
                     date <= date_post,
                    date != date) %>%
              mutate(period = ifelse(date<date, '1-day-pre', '1-day-after'))` libraries `library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)`

Comment: Is this different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58141008/keep-before-and-after-date-of-an-external-list/ ?