# Keep records before and after a specific timestamp

Tags: r, dplyr

Having a data frame which provides a specific timestamp

```
dframe1 <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), name = c("Google", 
"Yahoo", "Amazon", "Amazon", "Google"), date = c("2008-11-01", 
"2008-11-01", "2008-11-04", "2008-11-01", "2008-11-02")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

And a second one from which I would like to keep info before and after the specific time from the first dataframe

```
dframe2 <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), date = c("2008-11-01", "2008-11-01", 
"2008-11-04", "2008-10-31", "2008-10-31", "2008-11-02", "2008-11-02", 
"2008-11-02", "2008-11-05", "2008-11-02", "2008-11-03", "2008-10-31", 
"2008-11-01", "2008-11-01", "2008-11-02", "2008-11-02", "2008-11-03"
), text_sth = c("test", "text_sth", "text here", "another text", 
"other", "another one", "test", "text_sth", "text here", "another text", 
"other", "etc", "test", "text_sth", "text here", "another text", 
"text here")), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = "data.frame")
```

How is it possible to have this output?

```
id                               text_sth   name label
1                     another text other Google   before
1 another one test text_sth another text Google after
1                     another text other  Yahoo   before
1 another one test text_sth another text  Yahoo after
1                                  other Amazon   before
1                              text here Amazon after
```

Here is what I tried

```
library(dplyr)
dframe1 %>%
   mutate(date = as.Date(date), date1 = date) %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   tidyr::complete(date1 = seq(date1 - 1, date1 + 1, by = "1 day")) %>%
   filter(date1 != date | is.na(date)) %>%
   select(-date) %>%
   mutate(col = c("before", "after")) %>%
   rename(date = 3) %>%
   inner_join(dframe2 %>% mutate(date = as.Date(date)))
```

From dframe1 there are ids which are the same with dframe2. Using the frame1 date for every id I want to keep for every user his/her activity one day before and one day after the date of dframe1. And finally create a dataframe which contains id, merge text column, the name of dframe1 and a labeling before and after which is the one day before and the one day after date of dframe1

Comment: Some more explanation needed. It's not clear at all why e.g. "other" goes to Amazon before and "another text" doesn't. It has date "2008-10-31" which is before any of the Amazon's dates. What role does the `id` column play?

Comment: @IaroslavDomin. From dframe1 there are ids which are the same with dframe2. Using the frame1 date for every id I want to keep for every user his/her activity one day before and one day after the date of dframe1. And finally create a dataframe which contains id, merge text column, the name of dframe1 and a labeling before and after which is the one day before and the one day after date of dframe1

Comment: It would make sense to add this to the question body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Convert date strings to actual dates.

```
library(dplyr)

dframe1 <- mutate(dframe1, date = as.Date(date))
dframe2 <- mutate(dframe2, date = as.Date(date))
```

2. Collapse values of `text_sth` inside each `id`, `date` group in dframe2. They'll appear together anyways in the output.

```
df2 <- 
  dframe2 %>% 
  group_by(id, date) %>% 
  summarise(text_sth = paste(text_sth, collapse = " "))

df2
#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#> # Groups:   id [2]
#>       id date       text_sth                              
#>    <int> <date>     <chr>                                 
#>  1     1 2008-10-31 another text other                    
#>  2     1 2008-11-01 test text_sth                         
#>  3     1 2008-11-02 another one test text_sth another text
#>  4     1 2008-11-03 other                                 
#>  5     1 2008-11-04 text here                             
#>  6     1 2008-11-05 text here                             
#>  7     2 2008-10-31 etc                                   
#>  8     2 2008-11-01 test text_sth                         
#>  9     2 2008-11-02 text here another text                
#> 10     2 2008-11-03 text here
```

3. All the rest: join by `id`, keep only rows where difference between the date from the first df and the date from the second df is either 1 or -1. Depending on the sign, populate the `label` variable.

```
left_join(dframe1, df2, by = "id") %>% 
  mutate(date_diff = as.numeric(date.y - date.x)) %>%
  filter(abs(date_diff) == 1) %>% 
  mutate(label = ifelse(date_diff == -1, "before", "after")) %>% 
  select(id, name, label, text_sth)
#>    id   name  label                               text_sth
#> 1   1 Google before                     another text other
#> 2   1 Google  after another one test text_sth another text
#> 3   1  Yahoo before                     another text other
#> 4   1  Yahoo  after another one test text_sth another text
#> 5   1 Amazon before                                  other
#> 6   1 Amazon  after                              text here
#> 7   2 Amazon before                                    etc
#> 8   2 Amazon  after                 text here another text
#> 9   2 Google before                          test text_sth
#> 10  2 Google  after                              text here
```