# Keep rows until a specific timestamp even if the last one does not exists

Tags: r

Having a data frame which provides a specific timestamp

```
dframe1 <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), name = c("Google", 
"Yahoo", "Amazon", "Amazon", "Google"), date = c("2008-11-01", 
"2008-11-01", "2008-11-04", "2008-11-01", "2008-11-02")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

And a second one from which I would like to keep info before and after the specific time from the first dataframe

```
dframe2 <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), date = c("2008-11-01", "2008-11-01", 
"2008-11-04", "2008-10-31", "2008-10-31", "2008-11-02", "2008-11-02", 
"2008-11-02", "2008-11-05", "2008-11-02", "2008-11-03", "2008-10-31", 
"2008-11-01", "2008-11-01", "2008-11-02", "2008-11-02", "2008-11-03"
), text_sth = c("test", "text_sth", "text here", "another text", 
"other", "another one", "test", "text_sth", "text here", "another text", 
"other", "etc", "test", "text_sth", "text here", "another text", 
"text here")), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = "data.frame")
```

How is it possible to have this output?

```
id                               text_sth   name label
1                     another text other Google   before
1 another one test text_sth another text Google after
1                     another text other  Yahoo   before
1 another one test text_sth another text  Yahoo after
1                                  other Amazon   before
1                              text here Amazon after
```

Using this code it keeps results only if it find the two days before and after timestamps. How is it possible to change it and make it to keep until the two days before and after even if the before and after timestamps does not exist but all the previous days until then exist? From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58644885/11786778)

```
left_join(dframe1, df2, by = "id") %>% 
  mutate(date_diff = as.numeric(date.y - date.x)) %>%
  filter(abs(date_diff) == 2) %>% 
  mutate(label = ifelse(date_diff == -2, "before", "after")) %>% 
  select(id, name, label, text_sth)
```

Answer (score 1):

next time maybe point out your [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58643662/keep-records-before-and-after-a-specific-timestamp/58644885#58644885) and include the relevant bits of code, so for example, you need to convert the data first (like previously)

```
dframe1$date = as.Date(dframe1$date)
dframe2$date = as.Date(dframe2$date)
```

So using what @IaroslavDomin has nicely provided, you need to change the filter. What I am doing here is a bit different from his. I use dframe2 directly.

```
X = left_join(dframe1, dframe2, by = "id") %>% 
  mutate(date_diff = as.numeric(date.y - date.x)) %>%
  # change the filter here, >0 means not the same
  # < 2 means within 2 days 
  filter(abs(date_diff)>0 & abs(date_diff)<2 ) %>% 
  mutate(label = ifelse(date_diff <0, "before", "after")) %>% 
  select(id, name, label, text_sth)
```

Now we have the text with the labels. We group them and give a proper label

```
X= X %>% group_by(id,name,label) %>%
summarize(test=paste(unique(text_sth),collapse=" "))
```

If we head the final table:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 4
# Groups:   id, name [5]
      id name   label  test                                  
   <int> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>                                 
 1     1 Amazon after  text here                             
 2     1 Amazon before other                                 
 3     1 Google after  another one test text_sth another text
 4     1 Google before another text other                    
 5     1 Yahoo  after  another one test text_sth another text
 6     1 Yahoo  before another text other                    
 7     2 Amazon after  text here another text                
 8     2 Amazon before etc                                   
 9     2 Google after  text here                             
10     2 Google before test text_sth
```

Comment: Thank you. I checked it but the results keep also the values from the input data frame

Comment: what do you mean? I have edited the post to show results. which part is different from what you expect?

Comment: actually if you use this option you have again until specific days it doesn't take into consideration for example that there are data in two days if I have less than 4

Comment: ok so you want everything before and everything after? it's not very clear in your question. And your desired output is for 2 days