# Separate data using using the seconds of a date

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with different id and names. Here a small example

```
library(dplyr)
dframefull <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,1,1), name = c("Google", "Google", "Google", "Google", "Google", "Google"), date = c("26/8/2014 19:30:57", "27/8/2014 10:12:01", "27/8/2014 14:10:29", "27/8/2014 14:10:32", "27/8/2014 14:10:33", "3/9/2014 14:10:32"), mytext = c("text", "another", "text", "here", "other text", "text more"))

dframefull <- mutate(dframefull, date = as.Date(date))
```

I have a second dataframe which has specific dates. Like this

```
dframekeep <- data.frame(id = c(1), name = c("Google"), date = c("27/8/2014 14:10:32"))
dframekeep <- mutate(dframekeep, date = as.Date(date))
```

Based on the specific dates I would like to keep for 10 days before the date of the second dataframe the data into one row and after the exact second (:32 in the example) the other data for 10 days after.

Here an example of the expected output.

```
data.frame(id = c(1,1), label = c("before", "after"), name = c("Google", "Google"), mytext = c("text another text here", "other text text more"))
  id  label   name                 mytext
1  1 before Google text another text here
2  1  after Google   other text text more
```

How can I make it. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58644885/11786778) is a solution for days

Comment: so second dataframe has date `27/8/2014 14:10:32`, this means first group would be upto `17/8/2014 14:10:32` ? You question isn't clear

Comment: @YOLO yes the first group is based on this time

Answer (score 1):

Use `aggregate` where also comparisons are possible using `I()`.

```
a <- aggregate(mytext ~ id + name + I(date > dframekeep$date), dframefull, paste)
a
#   id   name I(date > dframekeep$date)                    mytext
# 1  1 Google                     FALSE text, another, text, here
# 2  1 Google                      TRUE     other text, text more
```

To get proper names and labels in one step you can use classical list notation.

```
b <- with(dframefull, 
          aggregate(list(mytext=mytext), 
                    by=list(id=id, 
                            label=factor(I(date > dframekeep$date), labels=c("before", "after")), 
                            name=name), 
                    FUN=paste))
b
#   id  label   name                    mytext
# 1  1 before Google text, another, text, here
# 2  1  after Google     other text, text more
```

Comment: in this how can you define to keep the last 10 days before and after date of the second dataframe?

Comment: You can add/subtract seconds to a date, so I suppose 10 days before would be `dframekeep$date - 10*24*3600`.

Comment: Sorry I receive this error `Error in factor(I(date > dframekeep$date), labels = c("before", "after")) : 
  invalid 'labels'; length 2 should be 1 or 1`

Comment: It's because all dates are greater than 10 days before `dframekeep$date` so you get just one factor level, try `labels=c("after")` will work in the example.

Comment: I think they are not most of them are 27/